# Error adding "Assignment List WebPar" in "Sharepoint Learning Kit" 1.8

Tags: sharepoint, windows-server-2012-r2, slk

Regards,

Please if anyone can help.

SLK install 1.8.2 on Windows Server 2012 with SharePoint 2013, I followed the instructions in this link (http://fragged.info/2012/06/getting-started-with-slk/) but in step "15 Add the" AssignmentListWebPart "to your page, find it under the Miscellaneous section." to add I get the following error

"You can show or import a Web part or Web form control on this page. The Microsoft.SharePointLearningKit.WebParts.AssignmentListWebPart, Microsoft.SharePointLearningKit, Version = 1.3.1.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 24e5ae139825747e type not found or it is not registered as safe. "

And check the config file and verify that the sure way "AssignmentListWebPart" is True.

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance for your valuable help.